# What happens to a mortal's photos/videos after they are embraced?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

As stated in the core rulebook, kindred images of any form (digital or printed) became distorted, blurry basically unidentifiable in an unnatural way. but it's not clear what happens to the older images, from the time the kindred was mortal. I always thought they also became foggy once you are embraced. But in this digital age it is more and more absurd and obvious, which would basically make it a lot easier for hunters to identify kindred just by browsing social media, which is exactly the opposite of why this power exists in the first place, which is to protect the masquerade.

If the old images stay sharp as they are, then basically a kindred can use her ID anywhere without raising any suspicions, at least a couple of years. which I always thought a big obstacle to create a fake photo of herself to use in ID's since they'd became blurred. Now I'm not sure. Can anyone clear my confusion?

Comment: added the parts it is mentioned in the book

Comment: @cpcodes generally, if you have to ask for relevant passages and have never played the system in question, you shouldn't attempt to answer as you don't have the expertise

Comment: @VolkanUlukut I've removed those quotes, but only because we should prefer this question to receive answers from those familiar with VTR, who would have the rulebook and who would be able to access those quotes trivially. Facilitating people who have no familiarity with the system or the rulebooks is inviting people to speculate answers from a position of ignorance -- we'd get crap answers based on the wrong lore or in conflict with VTR lore and that doesn't help anyone. To the extent providing the quotes is for the sake of inviting answers from nonexperts, we're probably better without them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nothing

Let's look at the problem in this way: What is a photo?

A photography or piece of film (analog or digital) or even a painted artwork is a snippet of the moment, burned into a medium forever. One might say, on a purely metaphysical level, it *captured a piece of the soul* of the human or it *freezes time* for the depicted scene. In all means, its depiction is very strongly bound to the moment it was taken, less to the people depicted. Vampires just don't show up in them nicely, they... lack the soul to be captured, so appear blurry.

Now, when getting embraced the human dies. Only some time later, when infused with vampire blood and finishing the transformation, a kindred is born. The soul is not staying to be the kindred's for all this time, it is gone. In all means, they are metaphysical separate entities - a human and an undead.

Now, what happens to pictures of a *human* that just happened to die? Their materials age and can be destroyed, but that's it. They are bound to the *moment of their creation* mainly, and that moment had a human being photographed. Some day, the picture will get faded or lost, but until then, the picture stays. It will be a constant reminder of the *person* that once was, unaffected by the monster that now is. The bond of the picture to the vampire is... weak at best and shouldn't affect the picture at all.

## The ID question

Now, as pictures don't change what is depicted if no supernatural force tampers with it, you might get away with using your old ID for quite some time, like a dozen years. Then you get to the day when you will have to change your birthday...

Now, what is a picture of a picture? It depicts what the picture used to show. It is bound to the state of the picture at that point in time, which again is bound to the state of reality as it was when taken... You might hand a picture of your picture in. Or a fresh copy of the picture, if you still have the negatives. You might retouch the picture some to try to adress changes to your looks - like exchange the visible part of the clothing.